# Class constructor BehaviorSubject cannot be invoked without 'new' In Bs Datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, datepicker

“I'm getting this error  while opening date picker Class constructor BehaviorSubject cannot be invoked without 'new'.

Comment: What have you tried and what is your current code? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: okay  @KarlChelton , i am new at Stack Overflow. now going to read your article, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found the solution which change i did and why this error showing to me. It's due to tsconfig.json changes

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2018", //"target": "es5", => due to this change
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018", //"es2016",, => due to this change
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "preserveWhitespaces": false
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error during opening datepicker from ngx-Bootstrap (in production version). But changing lib and target hasn't fixed it. It disappeared when I set 'aot' to false (and forced to set 'buildOptimizer=false') in angular.json under 'build' section. But I treat the fix as temporary one since it does not touch root cause.